# I want to extract href value from hyperlink through document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".indexed-biz-name");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write(x[i].innerHTML + "<br>");
}
```

When i run this code through greasemonkey it gives me `output` which is hyperlink in it. I want to extract the url within a same working.

Comment: x[i].href ? and please dont use document.write. its awful

Comment: @Jonasw it's I think only for his debugging. :) that would do i guess

Comment: unclear of what you're asking

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Below is a snippet that does that you want

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".indexed-biz-name");
document.write('</br></br>')
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   document.write(links[i].getAttribute("href")+'</br>');
}
```

```html
<a href="bla" class="indexed-biz-name">link1</a>
<br/>
<a href="blabla" class="indexed-biz-name">link2</a>
<br/>
<a href="blablabla" class="indexed-biz-name">link3</a>
```

Comment: If want full url use href property instead

Comment: Christos: You are a saviour.